# Unable to install Java1.8 in Windows7 machine?

Tags: java, windows-7, java-8

I have downloaded Java1.8 but when i am trying to double click on downloaded files(jdk-8u101-windows-x64 ) or `Right click->Run as Administrator` nothing happening ,even no error message.

Can someone tell me what can be issue ? or How to know what went wrong with downloaded files?

**EDIT**

Tried with command prompt as well

```
start jdk-8u101-windows-x64
```

It open a popup Window and ask

> Do you want to allow the following program to make changes in this
>   computer

I press `Yes` then nothing happened and its come to command prompt next line

Comment: What is the file exactly (zip/exe/msi)?  Have you tried running it from the command line?

Comment: Did you check whether some new process appeared in the windows task manager? Do you have (or had in the past) a multiple screen setup ? Sometimes windows tries to open applications on screens that are not connected anymore. -> windowsbutton + arrows helps here.

Comment: @SteveSmith Its exe file

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line?

Comment: @SteveSmith I edited question with command prompt thing

Answer (score 0):

I would try restarting the machine and trying it again, but if that doesn't work...

- Redownload the exe file to ensure that it isn't corrupted.
- Ensure that you have downloaded the right version for your machine
  (32 bit or 64 bit), you can check this in 'System' or typing
  Windows + Pause

If this doesn't work, use [Ninite](http://ninite.com) and select JDK and/or JDK x64.

Comment: Have you check the [installation log](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/log_files.xml)?